# I'm at a loss debugging my image handling system

Tags: php, laravel, image

i'll preface this by saying i'm still studying when it comes to building website, even more when it comes to using Laravel.

I'm currently building a portfolio. Its structure is rather simple, but where i'm having troubles is with the image handling for both the gallery and the actual expanded views for projects i register in there.

So far, i've managed to make a system that register a project in my DB with the following function in a controller :

```
    public function storeProject(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        // Valider les données du formulaire
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'image_1' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4000',
            'image_2' => 'file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4000|nullable',
            'image_3' => 'file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4000|nullable',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'url' => 'required|url',
            'customer' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'mission' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'tags' => 'nullable|array',
        ]);

        //dd($validatedData);

        // convert string to array
        $mission = $validatedData['mission'] ? [$validatedData['mission']] : [];


        //Save images


        $imagePaths = [];
        $images = [$request->file('image_1'), $request->file('image_2'), $request->file('image_3')];
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            if ($image) {
                $filename = time() . '-' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = $image->storeAs('public/images/' . $filename);
                $imagePaths[] = $filename;
            }
        }


        // New project with form data
        $project = new projet;
        $project->name = $validatedData['name'];
        $project->image_1 = $imagePaths[0] ?? null;
        $project->image_2 = $imagePaths[1] ?? null;
        $project->image_3 = $imagePaths[2] ?? null;
        $project->description = $validatedData['description'];
        $project->url = $validatedData['url'];
        $project->customer = $validatedData['customer'];
        $project->mission = $validatedData['mission'];
        $project->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $project->save();

        // tags
        $tags = $validatedData['tags'];
        $project->addtags($tags);
        // categories

        $project->addCategory($mission);
        return redirect()->route('gallery')->with('success', 'Projet mis en Ligne avec succès.');

        
    }
```

This part here seems to work correctly, images are stored, and fetched correctly in the views that call them. The issue i'm facing comes with the next block that's related to it, being a function to update an existing project. My edit system works with a form being submitted, as can be seen here :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Portfolio')

@section('content')

    <div class="admincontainers">
        <div class="mobilemenubar">
            @include('components.dropdown_menu')
        </div>
        <div class="column1">
            @include('components.admin_menu')

        </div>


        <div class="admin_column2">

            @include('components.messages')
            <form action="
            {{ route('update-project', $project->id) }} " class="projectForm" method="POST"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div>
                    <label for="name">Projet:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" required value="{{ $project->name ?? '' }}">
                </div>
                <div>
                    @if (isset($project->image_1))
                        <img width="100px" src="{{ asset("/storage/images/$project->image_1") }}" alt="">
                    @endif
                    <label for="image_1">Image 1:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image_1" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <div>
                    @if (isset($project->image_2))
                        <img width="100px" src="{{ asset("/storage/images/$project->image_2") }}" alt="">
                    @endif
                    <label for="image_2">Image 2:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image_2" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <div>
                    @if (isset($project->image_3))
                        <img width="100px" src="{{ asset("/storage/images/$project->image_3") }}" alt="">
                    @endif
                    <label for="image_3">Image 3:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image_3" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="description">Description:</label>
                    <textarea name="description" required>{{ $project->description }}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="url">URL:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="url" required value="{{ $project->url ?? '' }}">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="customer">Client:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="customer" required value="{{ $project->customer ?? '' }}">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="tags[]">Tags:</label>
                    <select name="tags[]" class="form-control" multiple>
                        @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                            <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="mission">Mission Réalisée:</label>
                    <select name="mission" class="form-control" multiple>
                        @foreach ($categorie as $category)
                            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::id() }}">
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="Edit">Editer le projet

                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script>
                let editButton = document.querySelectorAll('.Edit');

                for (let i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
                    deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                        if (confirm("Souhaitez-vous réellement modifier ce projet ?")) {
                            window.location.href = e.target.firstElementChild.getAttribute('href');
                        } else {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });

                }
            </script>
        @endsection
```

upon submitting the form, te route update-project is called, which launches the following function :

```
public function updateProject(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'image_1' => 'nullable|file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4000',
            'image_2' => 'file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4000|nullable',
            'image_3' => 'file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4000|nullable',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'url' => 'required|url',
            'customer' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'mission' => 'nullable|string|max:191',
            'tags' => 'nullable|array',
        ]);
        $mission = isset($validatedData['mission']) && !empty($validatedData['mission']) ? [$validatedData['mission']] : [];

        $project = Projet::find($id);
        if (!$project) {
            return redirect()->route('gallery')->with('error', 'Aucun projet trouvé');
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('image_1')) {
            // delete previous image
            Storage::disk('public')->delete('storage/images/' . $project->image_1);
            // Storage::delete($project->image_1);

            // store updated image
            $filename = time() . '-' . $request->file('image_1')->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $request->file('image_1')->storeAs('storage/images/' . $filename);

            $project->image_1 = $path;
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('image_2')) {

            // delete previous image
            Storage::disk('public')->delete('storage/images/' . $project->image_2);
            // Storage::delete($project->image_1);

            // store the updated image
            $filename = time() . '-' . $request->file('image_2')->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $request->file('image_2')->storeAs('storage/images/' . $filename);

            $project->image_1 = $path;
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('image_3')) {

            // delete previous image
            Storage::disk('public')->delete('storage/images/' . $project->image_3);
            // Storage::delete($project->image_1);

            // store the updated image
            $filename = time() . '-' . $request->file('image_3')->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $request->file('image_3')->storeAs('storage/images/' . $filename);

            $project->image_1 = $path;
        }

        $project->name = $validatedData['name'];
        $project->description = $validatedData['description'];
        $project->url = $validatedData['url'];
        $project->customer = $validatedData['customer'];
        // $project->mission = $validatedData['mission'];
        $project->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $project->save();

        $tags = $validatedData['tags'];
        $project->addtags($tags);
        // categories

        $project->addCategory($mission);

        return redirect()->route('gallery')->with('success', 'Le projet a été mis à jour avec succès.');
    }
```

And finally, here is one of my gallery views that have the images called to:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Portfolio')

@section('content')

    <div class="admincontainers">
        <div class="mobilemenubar">
            @include('components.dropdown_menu')
        </div>
        <div class="column1">
            @include('components.admin_menu')
        </div>

        <div class="admin_column2">
            @include('components.messages')

            @foreach ($projets as $project)
                <div class="project_preview">
                    <a href="{{ route('project', ['id' => $project->id]) }}">
                        <img src="{{ asset("storage/images/$project->image_1") }}" alt="{{ $project->name }}">
                    </a>
                    <div class="desc">
                        Nom du projet: {{ $project->name }}
                        <br />
                        Client : {{ $project->customer }}
                        <br />
                        <div class="TextDescription">
                            Description: {{ Str::limit($project->description, 200) }}
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="Mission">
                            Mission :
                            @foreach ($project->category as $category)
                                <span class="tag">{{ $category->name }}</span>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        Lien : <a href="{{ $project->url }}">{{ $project->url }}</a>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="technologies">
                            Technologies :
                            @foreach ($project->tags as $tag)
                                <span class="tag">{{ $tag->name }}</span>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <form action=" {{ route('edit-project', $project->id) }}" method="GET">
                                @csrf

                                <button type="submit">Modifier</button>
                            </form>
                            <form action="{{ route('delete-project', $project->id) }}"class="Delete" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit">Supprimer</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            @endforeach
            <a href="{{ route('add-project') }}">Ajouter un nouveau Projet</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        let deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('.Delete');

        for (let i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
            deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                if (confirm("Souhaitez-vous réellement supprimer ce projet ?")) {
                    window.location.href = e.target.firstElementChild.getAttribute('href');
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

This is where my issue occurs, where the new form, once submitted *does* update the project with the passed ID, but the images seems to break ( they wont show, will show the broken file icon, and return errors in the console that the image cant be reached)

So far what i've tried is :
I've tried changing the path of the images in the update function to public/storage/image, didnt work
I've ensured that i've set a php artisan storage:link, which does exist.

I've tried changind the $project->image_X = $path line to $project->image_X = public/storage/image . $filename instead of its current construction but it didnt work either

I dont see any critical flaw in my current logic, so i'd appreciate insight to help me open my eyes to anything glaringly obvious that i cant figure out

Comment: I'm guessing the answer provided is the source of your issue, but without a doubt you are missing out on best practices and the "laravel" way in having these giant controllers with all that code.  If you consolidate a lot of that logic into a class or 2 making it a service, and using the service container, you will greatly improve the quality of your code.  There should be one set of paths and those set by configuration in your service.

Comment: I appreciate the advice :D As i said i'm still learning, this project is my first time using Laravel ( and any framework tbh ) so it's very likely i'm not aware of many of the usual ways to handle things, the last time i did a project that handled crud was all manual php writing with an MVC model haha

Comment: Totally understand, we were all new at one time.  It's good to try and read about Laravel as a Dependency injection framework, and you want to be able to create your own classes that use the dependency injection philosophy.   You can begin by adding functions to your controller class that make code more DRY.  You repeat code many times (3x for 3 different images x2 (for new project vs update project). Break it up into functions that can for example, add a file or remove a file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some confusion on your part as to how Laravel's built in file storage system works.

This system is layered upon a [file system abstraction library](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) intended to make it easy to store and retrieve files on a variety of different storage systems using different protocols.

So the first thing to understand is that you can have different "disks" configured.  I am not going to touch upon this further, as you are just using the "local" disk, which is setup to store files locally on your server. In other words, the "local" disk is the default and assumed, because you are not passing the disk parameter in any of the method chains you are using.

You have to be clear on the concept of the webserver webroot, which is `project/public` for laravel.  In other words, the web server webroot directory is public.

Files in webspace need to be children of the public directory for the web server to see them.

Laravel, by default is going to store files outside of the webroot.  Exactly where these files are stored, and how you can then reference them in webspace is part of the configuration aspect of your app.

By default, laravel comes with a setting to put "public" files into the directory `project/storage/app/public`.

Under the `project/public` directory, which is the webserver webroot, there should not be a directory.

Using the `php artisan storage:link` command simply creates a symbolic link in the `project/public` directory named `storage` so that files that are actually stored in the `project/storage/app/public` directory can be referenced within webspace in url's etc as `storage/some_file_name`.

All the asset() helper is doing is referencing that and making url's from that path.

Your code is intermixing the real directory locations with the symlink urls with the additional paths.

Step back for a minute from what you have done, and [re-read the actual File Storage documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#storing-files).

Start with the `config/filesystems.php` file.  This is what drives the functionality of the the storage:link command.

By default you already have the public access feature I described.  There is no reason to then try and add additional subdirectories to the chained storeas wrapper, nor later to the code that deletes existing files.  It does not help you to do so.  When you store a file to the "default" location, you are storing it so it can be found again.  While you can add additional subdirectories to the mix, there is not a benefit to doing so in most cases.

TLDR:

Should store to here:

```
$path = $request->file('image_1')->storeAs($filename);
```

Then Delete with

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete($project->image_1);
```

Reference with

```
asset('storage/' . $project->image_1);
```

Now let's say you don't want these image files to go into the default public location that is reference in webspace (asset tag/url), but would rather these files be stored in an images directory.

Then configure that "disk" in filesystems.php (as illustrated in the manual).

```php
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
]
```

You would create a directory `project/storage/app/images` and then after making the alteration to the config/filesystems.php file, run the artisan storage:link command to make the symlink, which would let you reference your images as

```
{{ asset('images/' . $your_file_name) }}
```

You would store these files this way:

```
$path = $request->file('image_1')->storeAs('images', $filename);
```

And Delete via:

```
Storage::disk('images')->delete($project->image_1);
```

Reference in webspace:

```
asset('images/' . $project->image_1);
```